# Al definir una vector de cadenas de caracteres y la imprimo luego, en todas las posiciones siempre imprime el último valor, ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Tags: c++, string, printf

Estoy diseñando un código y necesito sacar algunos valores de una cadena de caracteres y luego guardarlos en un vector de cadenas de caracteres, pero cuando imprimo ese vector siempre sale el último valor Acá dejo el código:

```
char *vector_motor[5];
len=strlen(datos3);
    for(cont=0; cont<len; cont++)
    {
        if(datos3[cont]==':')
        {
            cont3=cont+1;
            band++;
            while(datos3[cont3]!=',' && datos3[cont3]!='}' && band>2)
            {
                cadena_num[cont2]=datos3[cont3];
                cont2++;
                cont3++;
            }
            cadena_num[cont2]='\0';
            cont2=0;
            if(band>2 && band<=7)
            {
                vector_motor[band-3]=cadena_num;
            }
        }
    }
    for(cont=0;cont<CANT_DATOS_2;cont++)
    {
        printf("%s",vector_motor[cont]; 
    }
```

cuando hago el for siempre imprime un mismo valor, como si todos las posiciones del arreglo se hubieran llenado con el mismo valor

Comment: Cuál es el valor de entrada y cuál debería ser la respuesta a imprimir? Qué pasa si `datos3` no contiene `:`?

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @Bicho, para resolver este tipo de problemas usualmente necesitamos un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Si no tenemos suficiente código para reproducir el problema lo mas que podemos hacer es suponer la causa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: La variable datos 3 contiene char datos3=" {"estado":"200 ok","carnet":"2151022","velocidad":1670.7,"frecuencia":58.55,"voltaje":194.44,"temperatura":45.08,"tiempo_init_op":1621055844824}"

Comment: pero el problema no es ese, el problema es que no se si estoy accediendo mal a el contenido de los apuntadores y cuando voy a escribirlos, siempre me da e último valor que es: 1621055844824